# SIM900 STK cannot browse through menu items with AT command set

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim900, sim-toolkit

I'm using a SIM900 module to browse the Sim Tool Kit menu and perform some actions. I'm able to get the top level menu but can't go further. Below is my AT commands and responses:

```
AT*PSSTKI=1

OK
AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT*PSSTK="SETUP MENU",1,1

OK

*PSSTK: "END SESSION"
AT*PSSTK="GET ITEM LIST",8

*PSSTK: "GET ITEM LIST",1,128,4,"eZ Reload",33,0,0

OK
AT*PSSTK="MENU SELECTION",1

+CME ERROR: operation not allowed
```

I receive an "ERROR" when I send the command to select the menu item.

[I'm using this SIMCOM official STK guide](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/AN_SIM900_STK_UGD_V1.00.pdf)

Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: If you turn on extended error reporting with `AT+CMEE`, you might quite possibly get a descriptive error response rather than just `ERROR` (although the error codes some times have to be taken with a grain of salt).

Comment: @hlovdal thank you for the tip, It says `+CME ERROR: operation not allowed`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AT*PSSTK="MENU SELECTION",1` has `item identifier` as argument, not index. Your example only has 1 item with identifier 128.

So I would try this: `AT*PSSTK="MENU SELECTION",128`

Comment: One small question though, I can't remove the menu once i setup `AT*PSSTK="SETUP MENU",1,1` but when i run this command `AT*PSSTK="REMOVE MENU",1` it gives me an error saying `+CME ERROR: operation not allowed` any idea?